# PYTHON: Submitting queries in APSX, and scraping results from aspx pages

Tags: python, asp.net, http

I want scrap Info from people in "http://www.ratsit.se/BC/SearchPerson.aspx", i am doing with following code written:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Origin': 'http://www.ratsit.se',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Referer': 'http://www.ratsit.se/',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'
}

class MyOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17'

myopener = MyOpener()
url = 'http://www.ratsit.se/BC/SearchPerson.aspx'
# first HTTP request without form data
f = myopener.open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
# parse and retrieve two vital form values
viewstate = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
#eventvalidation = soup.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION")[0]['value']

formData = (

('__LASTFOCUS',''),
('__EVENTTARGET',''),
('__EVENTARGUMENT',''),
#('__EVENTVALIDATION', eventvalidation),
('__VIEWSTATE', viewstate),
('ctl00$cphMain$txtFirstName', 'name'), 
('ctl00$cphMain$txtLastName', ''),  
('ctl00$cphMain$txtBirthDate', ''),                                                          # etc. (not all listed)
('ctl00$cphMain$txtAddress', ''),   
('ctl00$cphMain$txtZipCode', ''),  
('ctl00$cphMain$txtCity', ''),  
('ctl00$cphMain$txtKommun',''),
#('btnSearchAjax','Sök'),
)

encodedFields = urllib.urlencode(formData)
 # second HTTP request with form data
f = myopener.open(url, encodedFields)

try:
 # actually we'd better use BeautifulSoup once again to
 # retrieve results(instead of writing out the whole HTML file)
 # Besides, since the result is split into multipages,
 # we need send more HTTP requests
 fout = open('tmp.html', 'w')
except:
 print('Could not open output file\n')
 fout.writelines(f.readlines())
 fout.close()
```

i am getting response from server as "my ip is block" but is not true cause when i'm doing with the browser is working... any suggest where i am going wrong..

Thanks

Comment: The response message says, verbatim, "my ip is block"? Why can't people post proper error messages?

Comment: The number of searches on Ratsit is now limited per hour, day, week and month. The searches from this IP address has exceeded these limits and to continue the search requires a user agreement with Ratsit.

Comment: But, how i said is not true, cause if i use the browser is showing without problems.

Answer (score 0):

your code does not work.

```
  File "/Users/florianoswald/git/webscraper/scrape2.py", line 16
  version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17'
      ^
  IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

is that supposed to be a class definition? why do we need the `MyOpener` class anyway? this works as well:

```
myopener = urllib.FancyURLopener()
my.open("http://www.google.com")
<addinfourl at 4411860752 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x106ed1c50>>
```